# Show there exists a degree $ 3 $ polynomial such that....

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let be $[a,b]$ an interval. proof that there exists a unique polynomial $P$ of degree $3 $ defined by the values: $P(a), P(b), P''(a),P''(b)$ (indication: use the base {$  1, (x-a), (x-a)^2,(x-a)^3 $} )

My attempt:
I use Interpolation by Lagrange's Polynomials $$P(x)= P(a)+ P'(a)(x-a)+  \frac 1 2 P''(a)   (x-a)^2+ \frac 1 6 P'''(a)   (x-a)^3+ O((x-a)^4)$$ 
since P is a Polynomial of degree $3$ . we can write $$P(x)= \alpha x^3 +\beta x^2+ \gamma x + \delta $$
Any help pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's a particular polynomial of degree $3$. It can be written in the base $\{1, (x-a), (x-a)^2, (x-a)^3\}$ such as $$P(x) = \alpha + \beta(x-a)+\gamma(x-a)^2+\delta(x-a)^3$$

The uniqueness of $P$ will be demonstrated if $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and $\delta$ are unique when we only know $P(a), P(b), P''(a)$ and $P''(b)$

$P(a) = \alpha$ so $\alpha$ is unique.

$P''(a) = 2\gamma$ then $\gamma = P''(a)/2$ is unique.

$P''(b) = P''(a)+6\delta(b-a)$ then $\delta = \frac{P''(b)-P''(a)}{6(b-a)}$ is unique.

$P(b) = P(a) + \beta(b-a)+\frac{P''(a)}{2}(b-a)^2+\frac{P''(b)-P''(a)}{6(b-a)}(b-a)^3$ then $\beta$ is also unique.

This mean that $P$ is unique.

Comment: Thank You Very much !!! :)